# Ethereum transaction 'Exceeds block gas limit'

Tags: gas-limit

Title says it all!

More info:

Geth 1.3.5 Windows:

> eth.getBalance(MY_ADDRESS)
>   70000000000000000000
>
> eth.sendTransaction({from:"MY_ADDRESS", to:"TARGET_ADDRESS", value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"), gas:40000});

```
Exceeds block gas limit
    at InvalidResponse (<anonymous>:-81662:-170)
    at send (<anonymous>:-156322:-170)
    at sendTransaction (<anonymous>:-133322:-170)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I'm pretty new at this, so any suggestions or tips that may help me to resolve this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up, I've tried different gas values from 5 000 up to 5 000 000

Comment: Please make sure you specify at least 21000 gas (the cost of the transaction itself) and not more than 3000000, which can be the block gas limit at frontier. If you still see issues, please provide error messages for those specific ranges.

Comment: I've tried ranged from 5 000 to 5 000 000 all result in in what I've posted in my original post: "Exceeds block gas limit
    at InvalidResponse (<anonymous>:-81662:-170)"

Comment: Could you please open an issue on the GitHub issue tracker with as much detail as you can give us? Thanks! https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues